# Bundling context with intent

Tags: android

I was building an android app, and I needed to pass the current instance of a class to a service that I am launching from that class. So, like we bundle strings or many other datatypes to intent, something like this,

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmScreen.class);
intent1.putExtra("remainder", "example1");
intent1.putExtra("time", "example2");
startActivity(intent1);
```

Is there a similar way to bind context to intent and then pass it to the service to access the class's current instance of variables from the service class?

Comment: `public static String yourvariable` if you want to access the variable and its value

Comment: You need to make the class implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable` to pass to next Acitvty in extras.

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales You are correct but I don't want to pass string but context in this case.

Comment: @Spiker Thanks for the suggestion, it works but is there an easier method to access the context or current instance of a class from another class since Parcelable contains a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: Why do you need to send context in a service when you can get context directly from there?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I want to typecast the context to MainActivity and then access the current instance of a variable from there because, for certain reasons, I cannot declare that variable static. Like this, ((MainActivity)context)).variable

Comment: This means you need to work on architectural stuff. In this case you need to bind service or use some kind design patterns like observer, OR Event bus

Comment: I am glad it worked for you :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

EventBus worked, being a singleton class, it does not create duplicate instances.